# Getting a column of a data frame using a string/vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a function that looks like this :

```
foo <- function(dataframe, param)
{
   print(dataframe$param);
}
```

The "param" argument is a vector of the column name (as a string) of the same `data.frame` that I'll be passing to the function.

"df" say looks like this:

```
a b 
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

and, I call the function

```
foo(df, 'a')
```

I get some errors. How can I use the string literal to get the column of the data frame?

I'm new to R and have tried looking for the solution. Tried `toString` and `df$as.name(param)` but am getting errors.

Hope I've been clear with my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[` for extracting column

```
print(dataframe[,param])
```

Comment: @user3462769, in addition, you can use `drop = FALSE`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Steer clear of the `$` operator inside the function body, using vector operations (`[`) to access columns instead. Furthermore, `return` is the more generally accepted way to "print" the result from a function. The semicolon is unnecessary.

```
> foo <- function(dataframe, param)
  {
      return(dataframe[, param])
  }
> foo(d, "a")
## [1] 1 3 5
> foo(d, "b")
## [1] 2 4 6
```